# Dynamically setting background image using CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

While loading the animated emoji in my website, I want to show static image by default and then show animated emoji once the image is loaded.

I have used before pseudo element to load the animated Emoji Image, but once loaded, the static image is visible at the background.

Is there any way to hide the static image by just purely using CSS??

```css
.zcslymsg-anim-72-thumbsup
{
  background: url(/officechat/images/default/sm-animation/1-animsmiley72.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: auto;
    width: 72px;
    height: 72px;
    background-position: -519px 0px;
    animation:none;
}

.zcslymsg-anim-72-thumbsup:before
{
    content: "";
    background: url(/officechat/images/default/sm-animation/72/thumbsup.png) no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    background-size: auto;
    width: 72px;
    height: 72px;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: steps(120);
    animation-name: smileyanim-72;
    transform: translateZ(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
    image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;
}
```

```html
<em class="zcslymsg-anim-72-thumbsup" code=":thumbsup!:" title="Thumbs up"></em>
```

Comment: you can try inline styles.

Comment: Have you tried to use different class names and set/remove it when you emoji is loaded?

Comment: Thanks. But, I want to handle it by just using CSS not via javascript.